# Assemblies are removed after building the solution in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing windows application using 3-tier archtecture. So,i have created 
  two `ClassLibraries` that contains BAL and DAL

1.DAL -->I Put all the related connection to the database.

2.BAL -->All the business logic

Now the 3rd one is `Windows Forms` Application template. So my solution contains 3 projects:

- 2 class Library template projects
- and one windows Forms template  Project.

Now, when I add the reference dal.dll assembly into my `BAL` project, then I am using all the related connection object in my `BAL` Project.

Then, after that I have added `BAL` asembly means bal.dll into my `Windows Forms` application.Yes it is added succefully. And i run my project it is working fine.

But the problem comes after building the solution. The output window gives

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When I rebuild the solution, `BAL` reference or assembly could not be found.

I didn't understand what is the issue.Because I added those assemblies 
 successfully those are dot net dll's. The targeting framework is .Net FrameWork4.5. I checked that twice.

*Note: Those 3 folders under the same solution only. 
 Note: When i build the solution. In my BAL project..bin --->debug-->bal.dll and 
 dal.dll's are removed.This one also embarssing.*

Can you help me what's the issue here? Thanks

Comment: Do you add like "Add Reference->Solution->Your Projects"?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question for someone else to diagnose. As the previous comment suggests, you need to add the reference correctly; but perhaps you have and something else is wrong. We need at a minimum the _exact_ error text and build output. You should also include the .csproj files for any projects having an error, and maybe even the .sln file would be helpful.

Comment: No in my BAL project--->Right click on reference -->Add refernce-->Browse-->and select the path add add dal.dll file.Like that bal.dll file also in my window template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a project reference:

1. In **Solution Explorer**, select the project.
2. On the **Project** menu, click **Add Reference**. The **Add Reference** dialog box opens.
3. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
4. In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then click the **Select** button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple components.

**Update:**

For example:
To add `DAL` library to `BAL` library:

- Your BAL project -> Right click on **References** -> **Add
  reference** -> **Solution** -> select your DAL project

If you are using your `BAL` assembly at `DAL` assembly, you should add `BAL` assembly too like that:

- Your **DAL** project -> Right click on **References** -> **Add
  reference** -> **Solution** -> select your **BAL** project

Furthermore, you should add your all assemblies to `WinForms` application:

- Your **WinForms** project -> Right click on **References** -> **Add
  reference** -> **Solution** -> select your **BAL** and **DAL**
  project

**Update 2. Difference between your approach and standard approach:**
When you adding like you have said:

- BAL project--->Right click on reference -->Add
  refernce-->Browse-->and select the path add add dal.dll file.Like
  that bal.dll file also in my window template
  You just add the .dll to the the folder and your Solution cannot see this assmebly.

However, if you choose the adding by **Add Reference**, it is right way and all projects can connect with all projects in your solution.

Comment: I have added now,but when i run the solution the 0/p is same:========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Can u tell me the difference of addrefernce-->browse and addreference-->solution tab

Comment: @ let me give you an advice - accept all answers which help to you and which people give to you. It is really give motivation to people to help to you:).

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, as it should work the way you described it. Perhaps the dlls get deleted after the successful build.

However, the correct way to do it is to add references to the projects, not the assembly dlls. So for example:

BAL project => Right click on reference => Add reference => Solution => and select DAL project